# $L^1$-convergence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In my fourier analysis script we learnt that the fourier series of a function $f\in L^1[0,1]$ must not converge to $f$ in $L^1$, i.e. in general we have

$||S_n(f)-f||_{L^1[0,1]}\not\to 0$.

$S_n(f)$ are the symmetrical partial sums of the fourier series. Later, the author says that for all $f\in L^1[0,1]$ we have for all $x\in [0,1]$ that

$\int_{0}^xf(y)dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{x}S_n(f) dy$.

Isn't this for $x=1$ a contradiction?

Comment: No it's not a contradiction. For $x=1$ it says $\int_0^1(f-S_n)\to0$, but that's not $||f-S_n||_1$. The norm is $||f-S_n||_1=\int_0^1|f-S_n|$.

Comment: May not converge, not "must not converge".

Answer (score 0):

No, $\left|\int (f_n-f) dx\right|\to 0$ (the convergence you have) does not imply $\int |f_n-f|dx\to 0$ ($L^1$ convergence).

Comment: Thank you. Does this convergence (that we have) also have a name?

Comment: It is a special case of weak convergence. A sequence $f_n\in L^1$ converges weakly to $f\in L^1$ if for every $g\in L^\infty$, $\int f_n gdx\to \int fg dx$.

Comment: Thanks. I also know that for $f\in L^1[0,1]$ the Fourier series of $f$ do not have to converge pointwise (not even a.e.) to $f$. So this type of convergence is even weaker than a.e.-convergence?

Comment: Yes. Weak convergence is essentially the same as convergence of local averages. For example, $f_n(x)=\sin nx$ converges weakly to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Consider the following counterexample (not given by Fourier series, just an example in $L^1[0,1]$).

Let $f(x) = 0$, and $f_n(x) = 2^{n+1}1_{[2^{-n},2^{-(n+1)}]}(x)$. Then we have $f_n\to f$ pointwise, but
$$\|f-f_n\|_{L^1} = 1$$
for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you. But I also know that for $f\in L^1[0,1]$ the Fourier series of $f$ do not have to converge pointwise (not even a.e.) to $f$. So I wonder why the mentioned convergence holds.